# how to flush jenkins violations history

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, jenkins, reset

I have a [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) job setup which does calls [pmd](http://phpmd.org/), [phpcs](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) and [phpunit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) on every build. The home page of Jenkins job shows a chart of [violations](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Violations). I Need to flush/reset history of violations chart in Jenkins job. After resting the history, the history should start new with a new violations chart and data.
I do not want to reset the whole job history but only violations part of it. Cannot find where Jenkins stores its job history though `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs` has the proper job folder.

Using Ubuntu 11.04 with Jenkins 1.451

Comment: tried deleting the violations directory but did nto help. are you suggesting to deleting the whole build dir itself? Hope that won't crash existing jenkins job trying to reference non-existing dir/file

Answer (score 1):

in `http://<jenkinsAddress>/job/<jobName>/configure` you have `Discard Old Builds`. 
Set the `Max # of builds to keep`. It will remove old builds.

I installed jenkins in default directory (red hat/ubuntu). The builds are in:

`/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<jobName>/builds/` . Just remove them manually and restart jenkins ( or reload configuration from disk)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in the project directory (e.g. `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/projname`)...

Jenkins keeps details of each build in subdirectories of the `./builds` directory. The *Violations* plugin keeps detailed results in the `./violations` subdirectory of each build. It also keeps a summary of the violations in the main `build.xml` file for each build. In order to remove the violations history to need to remove all this information.

Removing the Violations data from `build.xml` while leaving the rest of it intact is best achieved with `xmlstarlet` or some other similar command line tool.

After removing the data from the various files you need to restart Jenkins to get it to recognize the changes.

These instructions should work on recent Ubuntu (assuming you are already in the correct project directory):

`sudo apt-get install xmlstarlet
sudo rm -rf ./builds/*/violations/*
sudo bash -c 'for BUILD in ./builds/*/build.xml; do xmlstarlet ed --inplace -d "/build/actions/hudson.plugins.violations.ViolationsBuildAction" $BUILD; done'
sudo service jenkins restart`